# Python JSON to tree with anytree

Tags: python, json, tree

I have JSON data that looks something like

```
{'Tree': [
  {"From": "1",
  "To": "2"},
  {"From": "2",
  "To": "3"}
]}
```

basically an array of all existing references between nodes. I want to be able to draw trees starting from a chosen root node using this data.

I find that using anytree I must link a node to a parent node, but ideally I want to simply link it to the name and have it put together the tree structure on its own.

```
# I want to do this
child[0] = Node(data[0]["To"], parent=data[0]["From"])

# But I think I need to assign a node, not its name
child[1] = Node(data[1]["To"], parent=child[?])
```

Suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Is there any meaning that makes From different from To, or are edges undirected, working on both ways?

Comment: Is the list guaranteed to be ordered so that no node (other than the root) is referenced via `"From"` before being referenced via `"To"`?

Comment: The edges are directed, from "From" and pointing to "To" nodes. The list is not guaranteed to be ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in two steps:

1. Convert the input format into an adjacency list: a dictionary keyed by the node keys, and with associated lists that hold the keys of the connected nodes.
2. Choose a root node, and then create the anytree tree using the adjacency list.

Here are two functions that deal with these two tasks:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
from collections import defaultdict 

def makegraph(edges):
    adj = defaultdict(list)
    for edge in edges:
        a, b = edge.values()
        adj[a].append(b)
        adj[b].append(a)
    return adj

def maketree(adj, nodekey):
    visited = set()
    
    def dfs(nodekey, parent):
        if nodekey not in visited:
            visited.add(nodekey)
            node = Node(nodekey, parent)
            for childkey in adj[nodekey]:
                dfs(childkey, node)
            return node
                
    return dfs(nodekey, None)
```

Here is how to use it:

```
edges = [
    {"From": "1", "To": "2"},
    {"From": "2", "To": "3"}
]

adj = makegraph(edges)
# Choose "1" as root:
root = maketree(adj, '1')
print(RenderTree(root))
# Now let's choose "2" as root:
root = maketree(adj, '2')
print(RenderTree(root))
```

Comment: It looks like recursive calls would far exceed the limit and I'll try to convert it to use loops.

Comment: Are you sure the input is a tree?

Comment: I guess the input is not a tree... In that case you could skip edges that would make a cycle while making the tree. See updated `maketree`.

Comment: You are exactly right, Cycles shouldn't exist in my data but it looks like they do exist. I converted your first ans to use loops and found it was a infinite loop caused by cycles in the structure. Thank you!

Comment: The updated function has some issues it looks like `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'`

Comment: That's an error in other code, because the code in my answer does not reference `children`. If you could link to a runnable example that produces this error, I'll have a look.

Comment: I ended up missing a line when copying and `root` was null, hence the error from `RenderTree()`. Thanks for your help, I'll also point out I removed `adj[b].append(a)` to only account for directed edges.